# Pymodbus is slow

Tags: performance, pymodbus

Reading multiple registers with modbus RTU at once is fast, but reading them one by one takes about one second.

(I have different type of power meter connected to the same communication bus and I have to read difference registers.)

Looked afrer on google, but didn't find the solution